# ListView Items and Subitems confusion

Tags: c, winapi

I am finding it difficult to understand what is the difference between ListView Items and Subitems. Are the entries in the first column called Items, while the entries in the rest of the columns called Subitems? If so, then when does this distinction becomes relevant?

Comment: Yes.  It is relevant because only a ListView with the LVS_REPORT style flag (aka "details view") has sub-items.  Other views only display the item text.  And only the item text is editable.

Comment: @Hans Passant But other than the naming, is the code to manipulate the Items different from the code to manipulate the Subitems, for example is the code to retrieve the text of the Items different from the code to retrieve the text of the Subitems?

Answer (score 1):

Subitems are only visible in certain listview modes. Report mode shows all the subitems while Tiles and Content only displays some of them.

A subitem cannot exist without its "parent"/main item. You create the item with `LVM_INSERTITEM` but you create subitems just by using `LVM_SETITEMTEXT`. Other item properties like `lParam` and `iIndent` only apply to the main item and in the first commoncontrol versions you could only set a image for the main item.

I'd recommend that you abstract away the details of allocating and retrieving item text buffers into a helper function. Something along the lines of `TCHAR* LVAllocAndGetItemText(HWND hLV, int ItemIndex, int SubItem = 0);`, most other listview interactions are often not generic enough or just apply to the main item (`iSubItem = 0`).

Comment: Doesn't `LVM_INSERTITEM` creates the Item as well as the Subitems (with an empty text), and later I use `LVM_SETITEMTEXT` to modify the empty Subitems text  (which can also be applied to the Item itself)?

Comment: If that helps you then you can imagine that LVM_INSERTITEM creates empty subitems but you have to remember that you can add more columns later and the listview probably does not bother storing empty text for who knows how many columns. LVM_SETITEMTEXT does work for both subitems and the main item...